# Help with writing script file for bitbucket repositories File System ChecK

Tags: shell-script, rhel, git

I have the below path for our Bitbucket repositories

```
/bbshared_storage/archive/data/repositories
```

The directories inside go by numbers (each number represent repository):
1000, 1001,1002 and so on.

Inside each repository, I have the repository-config file, which contains the project name:

```
[bitbucket]
    hierarchy = XXXXXX
    project = {The value I need}
    repository = XXX
```

I need to write a script that runs in a loop on all the repositories, with the `git fsck` command. In the end it must have a file that contains the repository name, with its fsck results: OK or error (I assume by using `echo $?` and asking if it's different from 0). Can you advise on a nice way to write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the below, although I guess there is a better way:

```
for /bbshared_storage/archive/data/repositories/*
do
    cd /bbshared_storage/archive/data/repositories/"$i"
    Rep=$(grep -E 'project|repo' repository-config |  tr '\n' ' ')
    git fsck
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]
    then
        echo "$Rep Good">>/tmp/BB_list.log
    else
        echo "$Rep Bad">>/tmp/BB_list.log
    fi
done
```

Comment: I made some significant changes to your script because you were doing some very dangerous things like parsing the output of ls, had some syntax issues and were using needlessly complex approaches. It's still not actually doing what the OP wants though. Have a look at your `$Rep` variable and the OP's example. Can you see what value it will have?

Comment: Tnx. I will check and update

Comment: It's simple, actually. The OP only wants the `project`, not the `repo` line. So you want something like `Rep=$(awk -F"=" '/project/{print $2}' repository-config)`.

Comment: I have a question on top of it. On some repositories, I do get error when running `git fsck` such as: `error: object directory /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/116/objects does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.
error: HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer 5f1e736a5fd1b21ea0f95fa62545d0fa4fc21049
error: refs/heads/feature/core-archetype: invalid sha1 pointer e731f9a441f35bbf3386e91191602164b9a63f37
` but at the end, the result is still good for them. how can I avoid it? I thought maybe modfiy the if condition with `if [[ $? == 0 ]] && [[ $error_count == 0 ]]` but it didn't help. any idea?

Comment: That will depend on whether this `fsck` thing exits with a non-0 status if it encounters an error. And on how you set this `$error_count` variable.

Comment: didn't get you... for the above if, I got 0 results... which doesn't make sense. also, why fsck returns 0 for it? maybe it worth new discussion :)

Comment: Yes, please don't do this in the comments. I am saying that I don't know how this tool works so I don't know if it will exit with a non-0 status if it encounters a problem. _You_ said that the result is stlll good even if there is a problem which suggests that it will not exit with a non-0 status if it finds problems. But yes, for more details, please ask a new question or maybe come into [/dev/chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat).